# Function that returns a list consisting of 40 random letters from (A-F)

Tags: python

I need to create a function called random_grades that returns a list consisting of 40 random letters from (A-F).
This is the code so far.. but i dont know how to make the output letters and not numbers...

```
import random 
random_grades = [random.randint(5,10) for i in range (40)]

A = 10

B = 9

C = 8

D = 7

E = 6

F = 5

print(random_grades)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map `index -> grade` aka an array, and the random variable is the index.

```
import random

grades = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
 
random_grades_indexes = [random.randint(0,len(grades)-1) for i in range (40)]
random_grades = [ grades[i] for i in random_grades_indexes]

print(random_grades)
```

Which prints

```
['D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'E']
```

As a proof that you will get a uniform distribution, we can create an histogram of the grades running 1000 grades.

```
import random

def count_elements(seq) -> dict:
    hist = {}
    for i in seq:
        hist[i] = hist.get(i, 0) + 1
    return hist

grades = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
 
random_grades_indexes = [random.randint(0,len(grades)-1) for i in range (1000)]
random_grades = [ grades[i] for i in random_grades_indexes]

dist = count_elements(random_grades)
print(dist)
```

Which gives

```
{'C': 175, 'F': 153, 'A': 153, 'E': 174, 'D': 174, 'B': 171}
```

Answer (score 3):

`random.choices` does it directly:

```
random.seed(0)  # make it reproducible
random.choices('ABCDEF', k=40)
```

give:

```
['F', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'C', 'E', 'E']
```

---

This works because a string is an iterable of characters...

Comment: python is delivered batteries included, this is the pythonic approach!

Comment: I like your pythonic approach. I have a curiosity though (note it wasn't required in the original question so **this is not a criticism**): in my answer one can tweak the `random_grades_indexes` array to have any distribution, one could sample a gaussian for instance. Is it possible with your approach?

Comment: @Fra93: yes, it is possible to assign different weights for the possible values. By default `choices` uses equal weights which gives a uniform distribution, but any (discrete) distribution is possible.